# Как отправить изображение дискорд ботом на Python используя библиотеку discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я пробывал сделать это получив channel

```
bot.get_channel(890665799608586262)
```

А потом попробывал отправить изображение так:

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File('reya.jpg'))
```

Но, консоль выдала ошибку: "Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.channel' has no attribute 'send'"
Я не знаю, что я сделал не так.
В общем вот вся функция

```
@bot.command()
async def foto(ctx):
    bot.get_channel(тут айди канала)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File('reya.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не определили переменную `channel`

```
@bot.command()
async def foto(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(тут айди канала)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File('reya.jpg'))
```